# How to configure Eclipse to skip Exceptions in debug mode?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to debug huge system which has many caught exceptions.
During debug process Eclipse stops on every exception, and I want to configure it to stop only on my breakpoint.

Is it any way to switch stopping on exceptions off ?

UPD.

- I use Helios Release.
- I already removed checkboxes from suspend on exception, and it did not helped.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In the Eclipse preferences, you can uncheck the option `Suspend execution on uncaught exceptions`, located in Java > Debug panel.

What is your Eclipse version btw?

Answer (score 6):

In the Preferences menu under Java -> [Debug](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/debug/ref-debug.htm) you can turn off *Suspend execution on uncaught exceptions*  That may help, as I expect although your codebase eventually catches exceptions, they are being thrown out of methods which are triggering this.

Answer (score 2):

In the Breakpoints view, check whether you have a breakpoint configured to stop on caught exceptions.

If there is such a breakpoint, you can uncheck the option to stop on caught exceptions, or delete the breakpoint entirely.

If the Breakpoints view is not visible, you can access it via Window>Show View>Other, under Debug>Breakpoints.